# how to cast (or convert) an ImageSource to FileImageSource

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

**The casting:**

```
Xamarin.Forms.FileImageSource image = (Xamarin.Forms.FileImageSource)MyImageSource;
```

compile, but generate an exception at run time:

*System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.*

In the opposite case, however, the casting is implicit when assign a 'FileImageSource' to an ImageSource

```
MyImageSource = Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource.FromFile(imagePath);
```

**How (if possible) the first conversion or casting can be done?**

In the following code, the idea is to define a class that can handle different sources and can be use as needed:

```
public class MyImage
{
    Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource MyImageSource;

    public MyImage(string source, Boolean from_resource = true)
    {
        if (from_resource)
            ReadFromResource(source);
        else
            ReadFromPath(source);
    }

    public void ReadFromResource(string resourceID)
    {
        MyImageSource = Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource.FromResource(resourceID); // resourceID = "App.Resources.image.png"
    }

    public void ReadFromPath(string imagePath)
    {
        MyImageSource = Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource.FromFile(imagePath); // imagePath = "/route/to/image.png"
    }

    public Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource GetIS()
    {
        Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource image = MyImageSource;
        return image;
    }

    public Xamarin.Forms.FileImageSource GetFIS()
    {
        Xamarin.Forms.FileImageSource image = (Xamarin.Forms.FileImageSource)MyImageSource;
        return image;
    }
}
```

Comment: The question content has been modified as You requested, for a very specific answer, the duplication you refer may be the example similarity but this question is not about buttons.

Comment: Additionally You mark this question as **duplicate**, and no way _How to set ImageSource as Xamarin.Forms.Button_ is "a duplicate" of _how to cast (or convert) an ImageSource to FileImageSource_. 
Moreover the answer talk about **ImageSource.FromStream** and Ii is not even mentioned here.

Comment: If You think the question still "duplicated", can You please show the **straight** answer, or show the procedure to solve this _controversy_ and allow some other one to help in this issue?